# Create unique rows in sheet A based on cell values in spreadsheets B and C

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Spreadsheets B and C have a column called create_case with data validation YES or NO. If the cell in the create_case column says YES I want to have a row created in spreadsheet A.

The trick is to create a unique row, in order, for each cell in the create_case column in spreadsheets B and C which has the value YES. See below.

SPREADSHEET B (first change from NO to YES happens here)

| name | create_case |
| --- | --- |
| Dan | Yes |
| Steve | No |

SPREADSHEET C (second change from NO to YES happens here)

| name | create_case |
| --- | --- |
| Mark | No |
| Chris | Yes |

## **OUTPUT:**

SPREADSHEET A

| case_id | name | create_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dan | date when row was created |
| 2 | Chris | date when row was created |

(create_time would be nice to have but not crucial for this question)

I tried an IF function but it doesn't help because it cannot create unique rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell in `Sheet A` in cell <kbd>A1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α,VSTACK('B:C'!A2:B3),
     ß,TAKE(FILTER(α,DROP(α,,1)="Yes"),,1),
     σ,HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(ß)),ß),
     VSTACK({"case_id","name"},σ))
```

---